# How to route all traffic via a local SSH SOCKS proxy on iOS?

Tags: ssh, iphone, proxy, socks-proxy, ios

Note: although iOS is technically for "cell phones" which aren't permitted on SU, this questions seems is technical and not about regular usage, that I consider it computer software.

I'd like to have the traffic of both Safari and apps routed through a remote linux server. I thought I would use the terminal app (obviously, the iDevice is jailbroken) to create a local SOCKS proxy with "ssh -D" to open a secure tunnel to the server.

How would I go about changing the global proxy settings to use the localhost proxy?

Any other ideas on achieving the same effect are most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be purely theory since I've never tried it myself but what about setting up a proxy auto-config (.pac) file for iOS that you have stored on your local filesystem.  And then you can reference that file through the Settings on your iOS.

I dug up this old link which details how to do it if the .pac file is stored on a shared location on the network but it could easily be modified to point to a local file.

http://snipplr.com/view/16563/how-to-connect-to-a-socks-proxy-from-an-unjailbroken-iphoneipod-touch/